# Syntax highlighting colors change between emacs and emacs -nw

Tags: themes

I am using Mac OS X Monterey.  I have the following settings in .emacs

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'liso t)

but I noticed that these settings are not valid for emacs -nw.

How can I find what theme is used for emacs -nw?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not invalid, it’s just that `emacs -nw` tells Emacs not to open a GUI window. It stays inside the terminal instead. Your terminal only allows a limited color palette, usually just 16 colors, but sometimes 256. Of course the colors from your theme are going to be replaced with colors from the palette; there’s nothing else Emacs can do.

Comment: Thank you - I added to .bashrc a line with "export TERM=xterm-256color"; the colors are close between emacs and emacs -nw, but not identical.  Anyhow, it is much better and I can read the text.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it sounds like you're comparing with 24-bit "true" colour in the GUI.

Emacs *can* use 24-bit colour in a terminal -- provided that (a) the terminal actually supports it, and (b) that ability has been identified to Emacs.

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html
or: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(efaq)Colors on a TTY`

Ideally there's a `TERM` value which correctly identifies the terminal you're using and its colour capabilities, but also note that "If Terminfo database is not available, but 24-bit direct color mode is supported, it can still be enabled by defining the environment variable `COLORTERM` to `truecolor`."

If the terminal emulator you're currently using doesn't support 24-bit colour, there will be others which do.

---

Failing any of that, note also that faces can be customized differently for different terminals.  If you go to the customize UI for a face and go to "State -> For All Kinds of Displays" and then "INS -> Display -> specific display" you'll see that you have *very* detailed control over how Emacs displays faces on various different terminal types.